# Express js bodyparser post req.body not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, mongoose

I try to build an api with express js post request. I use body-parser for req.body . But after sending post request i couldn't get any message still loading then show timeout. where is my problem please take a look my code.
I am testing it from postman and use on header content-type application/json.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const config = require('./config/config.js').get(process.env.NODE_ENV);
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();
mongoose.connect(config.DATABASE)
const {Book} = require('./models/book')

app.use(bodyParser.json())

// Post Book
app.post('api/book', (req,res)=>{
    let book = new Book(req.body)

    book.save((err, doc)=>{
        if(err) return res.status(400).send(err);
        res.status(200).json({
            post:true,
            bookId: doc._id
        })
    })
})
```

Now error show- cannot post /api/book 
but when i try with this below code its working--

```
const book = new Book({ name: 'Zildjian' });
book.save().then(() => console.log('data save'));
```

Comment: Could you show your schema and req.body ?

Comment: what is your `cookieParser`, post it

Comment: i remove cookieParser. but still error. pls check my updated question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your route from `api/book` to `/api/book` - add a leading `/`.

Also, it looks like it might be timing out as it can't get passed your **cookie-parser** middleware.

You have passed the function:

```
app.use(cookieParser)
```

...but you need to invoke it:

```
app.use(cookieParser())
```

You will also need to import it:

```
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
```

...or just remove it completely if you don't need it.

I hope this helps.

Comment: i remove cookieParser. but still error. please check my updated question. Thanks

Comment: Try changing your route from `api/book` to `/api/book` (add leading `/`).